# files moved or erased from zfs drive don't free space on the drive

Tags: disk-usage, zfs

I'm using ubuntu 21.10, installed anew with zfs filesystem.
If I delete some files, and then empty the trashcan, or move them to another (external) drive) this doesn't free up space on the drive.
actually df shows:
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zooqq5                           35G  4,5G     31G  13% /
where 35GB is the drive size.

Every time I add some file to the disk, the drive size decrease.

I recover space (and drive size goes up) by deleting zfs snapshots with a script, but how can this be right?

Maybe it's a bug?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [take the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) to learn how Ask Ubuntu works. Read [how to ask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Then take a look to [the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.

Answer (score 2):

Removed files are still referenced by past snapshots, so what you describe is expected behaviour.

As you already observed, the space remains used due to snapshots; only after deleting the last snapshot that references the deleted files will the corresponding space be available again for new files.

Note that [`df` does not provide accurate values for free space in ZFS file systems](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1448/gbchp.html). ZFS uses one or more disks (or partitions) to store pools that can contain one or more datasets (interpreted by `df` as filesystems), all of which share the pool's free space. Snapshots also fill up the pool (as part of datasets), further affecting the 'Size' `df` reports for an individual file system. ZFS is both a file system, a volume manager, and optionally manages RAID arrays; it would be analogous to, e.g., ext4 on LVM optionally on RAID.

To see how pools correspond to disks or partitions, you can use `zpool status`. In Ubuntu, you can find the listed disks or partitions under `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` and `/dev/disk/by-partuuid/` respectively. To see the free space in pools, you can list all pools via `zpool list`. You can list all ZFS datasets ("file systems") via `zfs list`, where the `USED` column indicates the space used by the dataset, which includes the files, child datasets and snapshots belonging to a specific dataset; `AVAIL` indicates the remaining space in the pool, and `REFER` indicates the size of the files specific to this file system, i.e., not snapshots or child filesystems.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: Thanks for the info!
"Removed files are still referenced by past snapshots, so what you describe is expected behaviour"
I understand and agree to this technical opinion but my point is that in a desktop environment not in beta or other development status this shouldn't happen.
ZFS on last version of Ubuntu is not marked as "experimental" and that's the reason I decided to try it.
But for a file system to not make available the space freed by deleting files is something absurd in my opinion

Comment: Happy to help! Since you do not like that snapshots prevent you from freeing disk space immediately, you are welcome to disable them: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233049/disable-automatic-zsys-snapshots-zfs-on-root. If you feel strongly that you should not have to do this, you could file a bug report requesting Canonical to disable ZFS snapshots out-of-the-box: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu.

If you feel your question is answered, please mark the answer as accepted.